# Lower case "k" in Cocoa

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I know this is a common convention, but what does the "k" in variable names signify? (i.e. kMaxImageViewSize)  I looked in the Apple documentation on Variable names and found no mention of it.

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 71, accepted):

That's a general programming notation not specific to Objective-C (i.e. Hungarian Notation) and the "k" stands for "constant".

Comment: I prefer my spelling of it, but of course your answer is just as correct. :-)

Comment: Does Apple still prefix it's constants with 'k'?

Comment: Then why use a hungarian notation at all? (Or better "Why did they use it at THAT time?")

Comment: For the record, "Hungarian Notation" has no concept of a prefix that means "constant".

Answer (score 25):

I would presume it means "konstant". :-)

Comment: Actually, it’s koefficient. Old mathematical tradition. :-)

Comment: “Koeffizient” is the German word for “coefficient“ i.e. a multiplication factor, whereas “Konstante” means the noun “constant“, which would here be appropriate. As the prefix “k” comes from the Hungarian notation, i would rather believe that it is derived from the Hungarian noun “konstans”, which also means “constant”.

Comment: Sorry @michael-manner, "k" does not come from Hungarian.  Look at the wikipedia entry, or the MSDN article; there is no mention of a "k" prefix and the only mention of anything special for constants is mentioned in passing when MSDN notes "Even if we know that it is a constant (because it is spelled all caps, for example), there might be several color-related types."

Comment: Now we historians need to find out the back story of the mysterious `k` used by ancestors since dozens of years ago.