# What does the kCF prefix mean?

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

Many constants in CoreFoundation have the kCF prefix. What does it mean?

[image]
[image]

Comment: "[…] constants in CoreFoundation" – well, just that. `k` for "constant", `CF` for "CoreFoundation".

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Any references? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both [OS X Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemFrameworks/SystemFrameworks.html) and
[iOS Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html)
you find a list of system frameworks together with the key prefixes used by the classes, methods, functions, types, or constants of the framework.

This list contains

```
Name                      Prefix
--------------------------------
...
CFNetwork.framework       CF
...
CoreFoundation.framework  CF
...
```

So there are actually several frameworks using the "CF" prefix, but
Core Foundation is the most "prominent" one.

The "k" prefix for constants is documented in
[Naming Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/NamingConventions.html)
in "Introduction to Core Foundation Design Concepts"
(emphasis added):

> A major programming-interface convention in Core Foundation is to use
>   the name of the opaque type that is most closely related to a symbol
>   as the symbol’s prefix. For functions, this prefix identifies not only
>   the type to which the function “belongs” but usually the type of
>   object that is the target of the function’s action. **(An exception to
>   this convention are constants, which put “k” before the type prefix.)**

As an example, `kCFAllocatorMalloc` is a constant related to
the [`CFAllocator` type](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFAllocatorRef/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Predefined_Allocators)  which is part of the Core Foundation framework.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patient!

Answer (score 0):

`k` stands for `Constant` & `CF` stands for `Core Foundation`

Comment: Any references? Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little curious about that why don't use first characters `c` of constant.

Comment: I think `k` stands for `key`

Comment: check the definition...  (An exception to this convention are constants, which put “k” before the type prefix.)

Comment: discussion for 'k' naming - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064794/what-does-the-k-stand-for-in-cocoa-constant-names