# Inventor Object Model understanding

Tags: api, autodesk, autodesk-inventor

what is the meaning of prefix of 'k' or other prefix in inventor API

I tried posting in autodesk but those people also don't know

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing with lowercase "k" is generally used to indicate a constant. This is evident when looking at all of Inventor's enums.
Example:

```
ButtonTypeEnum.kAcceptButtonType 
ButtonTypeEnum.kCancelButtonType 
ButtonTypeEnum.kEditButtonType
```

See this stackoverflow post: [What is the significance of starting constants with 'k'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500030/what-is-the-significance-of-starting-constants-with-k)