# What does the 'k' prefix indicate in Apple's APIs?

Tags: objective-c, hungarian-notation

I've run across many examples of Core Foundation variables named `k` + `someVariableNameHere` or `k` + `APILibraryName(2Char)` + `someVariableNameHere`.  What does this prefix `K` indicate?

Examples include:

`kGLPFAStereo`
`kCollectionLockBit`
`kSetDebugOption`

Comment: +1 Thanks for the question.  I was wondering about this myself just yesterday.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The k means constant in hungarian notation... see [Lower case "k" in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472103/lower-case-k-in-cocoa/472118#472118).

Answer (score 1):

This is a naming convention from the early days of macintosh programming. It indicates a constant.