# Objective C - Why do constants start with k

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions, constants

Why do constants in all examples I've seen always start with k? And should I #define constants in header or .m file?

I'm new to Objective C, and I don't know C. Is there some tutorial somewhere that explains these sorts of things without assuming knowledge of C?

Comment: By the way, an excellent tutorial in Objective-C that does *not* assume you already know C: *Programming in Objective-C* by Stephan G. Kochan, from InformIT.com. http://www.informit.com/store/programming-in-objective-c-9780321887283

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Starting constants with a "k" is a legacy of the pre-Mac OS X days. In fact, I think the practice might even come from *way* back in the day, when the Mac OS was written mostly in Pascal, and the predominant development language was Pascal. In C, `#define`'d constants are typically written in ALL CAPS, rather than prefixing with a "k".

As for where to `#define` constants: `#define` them where you're going to use them. If you expect people who `#import` your code to use the constants, put them in the header file; if the constants are only going to be used internally, put them in the `.m` file.

Comment: Interestingly, Google Code Style Guide requires constants to start with a 'k' as well.  I am amused when people who hate hungarian notation use this convention.  :)

Comment: I decided to put my constant in the .m file, after the #imports and before the @implementation.

Comment: Can't you also make a .h file for constans and then do extern const something something? How does that work?

Comment: You can, if you want. #defines work the same way. If you want a C "const" variable, you can do something like `extern NSString * const MY_CONST` in a .h file, and then in a .m file make a global `NSString * const MY_CONST = @"My Constant";` -- the `extern` keyword just means the constant is defined in another file.

Comment: Are there any advantages to using that method?

Comment: `#define` is basically a search-and-replace; so if you `#define MYCONST @"My Constant"`, then a string will be allocated everywhere you use `MYCONST`. However, if you use `extern NSString * const MYCONST = @"My Constant";`, the string will only be allocated once, and all uses of `MYCONST` will point to the same string. For other `#define`'d datatypes (e.g., `#define MYCONST 4.0`), it makes little difference.

Comment: Apple was using this way back in 1995 when I was programming the Apple Newton (both newton script, and C). https://www.newted.org/download/manuals/NewtonScriptProgramLanguage.pdf

Answer (score 9):

[Current recommendations from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146-SW1) for [naming constants](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-1001783) don't include the 'k' prefix, but many organizations adopted that convention and still use it, so you still see it quite a lot.

Answer (score 8):

The question of what the "k" means is answered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675816/what-does-the-k-prefix-indicate-in-apples-apis).

And if you intend for files other than that particular `.m` to use these constants, you have to put the constants in the header, since they can't import the `.m` file.

You might be interested in Cocoa Dev Central's [C tutorial for Cocoa programmers](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000081.php). It explains a lot of the core concepts.

Answer (score 6):

The `k` prefix comes from a time where many developers loved to use [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) in their code. In Hungarian notation, every variable has a prefix that tells you what type it is. `pSize` would be a pointer named "size" whereas `iSize` would be an integer named "size". Just looking at the name, you know the type of a variable. This can be pretty helpful in absence of modern IDEs that can show you the type of any variable at any time, otherwise you'd always have to search the declaration to know it. Following the trend of the time, Apple wanted to have a common prefix for all constants.

Okay, why not `c` then, like `c` for "constant"? Because `c` was already taken, in Hungarian notation, `c` is for "counter" (`cApple` means "count of apples"). There's a similar problem with the `class`, being a keyword in many languages, so how do you name a variable that points to a class? You will find tons of code naming this variable `klass` and thus `k` was chosen, `k` as in "konstant". In many languages this word actually does start with a k, [see here](http://ukdataexplorer.com/european-translator/?word=constant).

Regarding your second question: You should not use `#define` for constant at all, if you can avoid it, as `#define` is typeless.

```
const int x = 10;           // Type is int
const short y = 20;         // Type is short
const uint64_t z = 30;      // Type is for sure UInt64
const double d = 5000;      // Type is for sure double
const char * str = "Hello"; // Type is for sure char *

#define FOO 90
```

What type is FOO? It's some kind of number. But what kind of number? So far any type or no type at all. Type will depend on how and where you use `FOO` in your code.

Also if you have a fixed set of numbers, use an `enum` as then the compiler can verify you are using a valid value and enum values are always constant.

If you have to use a define, it won't matter where you define it. Header files are files you share among multiple code files, so if you need the same define in more than one place, you write it into a header file and include that header file wherever that define is needed. What you write into a code file is only visible within that code file, except for non-static functions and Obj-C classes that are both globally visible by default. But unless a function is declared in a header file and that header file is included into a code file where you want to use that function, the compiler will not know how this function looks like (what parameters it expects, what result value it returns), so it cannot check any of this and must rely that you call it correctly (usually this will cause it to create a warning). Obj-C classes cannot be used at all, unless you tell the current code file at least that this name is the name of a class, yet if you want to actually do something with that class (other than just passing it around), the compiler needs to know the interface of the class, that's why interfaces go into header files (if the class is only used within the current code file, writing interface and implementation into the file is legal and will work, too).

Answer (score 3):

k for "konvention".  Seriously;  it is just convention.

You can put a #define wherever you like;  in a header, in the .m at the top, in the .m right next to where you use it.  Just put it before any code that uses it.

The "intro to objective-c" documentation provided with the Xcode tool suite is actually quite good.  Read it a few times (I like to re-read it once every 2 to 5 years).

However, neither it nor any of the C books that I'm aware of will answer these particular questions.  The answers sort of become obvious through experience.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because of the former prevalence of Hungarian Notation, so k was chosen because c stood for character.  ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation )

--Alan