# Why do variable names start with the letter 'k'?

Tags: variables, v8, naming

such as kFastDtoaMaximalLength in fast-dtoa.h(Google v8)

is it represent kernel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "k" actually indicates that this variable is a constant (konstant?)

It's a use of Hungarian Notation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)

see: [Objective C - Why do constants start with k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230854/objective-c-why-do-constants-start-with-k)