# Objective-C contstants key naming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, naming-conventions

I'm little bit confused about constants naming.

`kName`
`NameKey`
`NAME_KEY`

Definitely usage of these fashions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to pick your own project or company prefix (like NS or AV above) and stick with it. So, if your prefix is AB:

- `ABMegaTopKey` for `const` variables
- `AB_MEGA_TOP_FLAG` for #defines

Apple uses different style depending, I guess, on who wrote the project and when was it written.

Answer (score 2):

According to Coding Guidelines for Cocoa, constances created with const shoul look like this:

> The format for const constants is exemplified by the following declaration:
>
> > const float NSLightGray;

To see guidelines [click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-1001783)

Answer (score 0):

`kName` is used for string or variable constants.
`NAME_KEY` is used for #define constants.

Comment: That doesn't seem right, look at AV Foundation Error Constants: "NSString *const AVErrorDeviceKey;" for example, they are not prefixed.

Comment: AV is the prefix of the framework, but in your code, your constants are never named like that.

Answer (score 0):

kName is Apple style, while NAME_KEY is alot more widespread among other languages. Doing a lil more research: k [is hungarian notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472103/lower-case-k-in-cocoa/472118#472118)

Answer (score 0):

I always use the third style coming from a mainly C background, although I will usually put a prefix on them for frameworks e.g.

```
NSString* const JP_NAME_KEY = @"name";
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a few visible 'cultures' in naming constants across the libraries.

I typically declare constants quite literally, using upper Camel with underscores to separate the longer names:

- Prefix with organization code
- then prefix with library (if applicable)
- then prefix it by type or category

  `ORGConstantName`

  `ORGLibrary_ConstantName`

  `ORGLibraryType_ConstantName`

  `ORGLibraryCategory_ConstantName`

it's verbose, but it avoids clashes, and it's really clear when the constant applies only to a certain scope, type, library, or other context.

whatever you settle on, just make sure it's consistent.